# Flow aligned right

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

In my QML file, I'm using a `Flow` type. I want the items put in the `Flow` to be aligned right, but `Flow` normally aligns from left to right, as in this picture:

[image: LTR Flow aligned right]

The Flow type provides an option to change layout direction, `layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft`, but in this case the order of the items will be wrong: first line will show `2 1 0`, second line: `4 3`, third line `6 5`.

There doesn't seem to be an option in the `Flow` type to keep flowing the items LTR but align them right.

I've been first trying to replace the `Flow` with `Column` and `Row`  types handling the positioning logic myself but it became ugly.

Now I'm thinking about extending the original `Flow` object to add an extra option. I'm considering taking the `Flow` source code and tweak it to make my own `ExtendedFlow` type.

Is there an easier/cleaner way to achieve this? What would be your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would have wrote this as a comment, if stackoverflow didn't restrict me from commenting on question for not having a reputation of atleast 50 points.

I can see an answer in your question. You said "The Flow type provides an option to change layout direction, layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft, but in this case the order of the items will be wrong: first line will show 2 1 0"

(If your program logic allows you to do this way)Why not Change layoutDiretion: Qt.RightToLeft and then change the order of your itemsto 2,1,0 so that they will be shown as 0,1,2.

This is much simpler and quicker than taking the Flow source code and tweak it to make your own ExtendedFlow type.